# Astaro Security Gateway AD SSO

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, single-sign-on

I have joind a **Astaro Security gateway** to the domain. And I am able to authenticate correctly when i set the Proxy profile to transparent mode with authentication. However, I would like to get SSO to work, however when I select SSO with AD it doesent seem to authenticate causing it to bump to the default content filter.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this mode it is not a altered transparent firewall like the AD (non-SSO) Authentication is. I setup GP to change the proxy to point to the firewall on port 8080. The correct filter profile was then being retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Transparent with Authentication works very well if you have another network off the **Astaro** that is separated from the one containing the DCs, it will prompt for AD authentication for workgroup computers on that network. I have implemented this in a unique environment and it works very well.